# Fullcalendar 4: How to get the element ref of the dropped event on fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am working on fullcalendar and need to get the element ref of event that is being dropped onto the calendar.

I need to show a confirmation box overlay and in order to set it correct location on the calendar,  I need exact element ref of event added on the calendar.

In that overlay, I need to show some custom message and based on user response, need to add event to calendar.

I tried the following :

```
this.calenderOptions = {
  contentHeight: 300,
  plugins: [resourceTimelinePlugin, interaction],
  editable: true,
  header: {
    left: "prev,next",
    center: "title",
    right: "prev"
  },
  resources: this.resources,
  events: this.calendarEvents,
  defaultView: "resourceTimelineDay",
  timeZone: "local",
  droppable: true,
  eventPositioned:(info) => {
    // This gets triggered as soon as  I enter the calendar.
  },
  eventReceive: (info) => {
    The info object does not have the element ref of dropped element/
    console.log(info);
  },
  slotLabelFormat: {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    meridiem: false,
    hour12: false
  }
};

new ThirdPartyDraggable(gridEL, {
  itemSelector: ".ag-row",
  eventData: eventEl => {
    let rowId = eventEl.getAttribute("row-id");
    let data = this.commonService.grid_service.getRowNode(rowId);
    return {
      title: data.data["shipmentId"],
      duration: data.data["est"],
      color: "#0000FF",
      className: "test",
      extendedProps: [
        {
          est: data.data["est"],
          shipmentId: data.data["shipmentId"]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: why not just put the confirmation box centred on the screen?

Comment: Hi ADyson, I have a UI requirement to show a popover near the event . Is it not possible?

Comment: But if you really need it, the [drop](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/drop) event also occurs when you drop an event on the calendar, and it contains a reference to the HTML element and the JS event which occurred (which itself contains things like click co-ordinates)

Comment: P.S. eventReceive _does_ also contain a reference to the HTML element - `info.draggedEl` - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive

Comment: Alternatively, another way you could attach a popup is via the [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) callback - there's even an example of attaching a tooltip given on that documentation page.

Comment: I checked the drop event response and eventReceive response. They contain the reference of draggable element on grid, but not on the elementRef in calendar , after dropping

Comment: Ok I see. Then i think you will need to use eventRender, as per my last comment. fullCalendar is presumably creating a new element to place on the calendar.

Comment: eventRender works after the event got dropped and now we want to edit DOM of rendered event. I need to show a confirmation overlay before the event can be dropped.

Comment: In that case you're out of look positioning-wise. Logically, you can't position something near an element which hasn't been rendered yet, because it doesn't exist...! Why not just show the confirmation over the top of the event (so you can't see it's been rendered), and if the user declines, you can delete it from the calendar before removing the popup.

Comment: P.S. last thing: did you try in the `drop` callback getting the X/Y coordinates from the JsEvent? am guessing that might tell you where the drop occurred, and you could set an absolute position for your popover (rather than relative to an element).

Comment: Thank you Adyson for all the help. I will confirm with BA's if they are ok with a popup at center, else will try with Js event.

Comment: Agreed. It seems a small thing to go to such trouble for. But surely you should be consulting the UX designer, not the BA?

Comment: Ops you got it right. I will check with UX :D

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be something like

```
eventReceive: function(info) {
  console.log("eventReceive title " + info.event.title + " start " + info.event.start.toISOString() + " end " + info.event.end + " id " + info.event.id + " description " + info.event.extendedProps.description + " delta " + info.delta);
},
```

instead of

```
eventReceive: (info) => {
   console.log(info);
},
```

Comment: I am using Fullcalendar in Angular 7. If I use this : function(info)  , then i cant access this reference.